# AutoIt - ControlClick on Flash content

Tags: flash, automation, autoit

Ok, I'm trying to automate closing multiple tickets on my job's ticketing system, which is browser based and built on flash (it's atrocious). Using the AutoIt v3 Window Info, I was able to get most of the information, but the clicks aren't registering. I understand that the window has to be active for ControlClick to work, but nothing progresses.

**Code:**

```
While 1
$msg = GUIGetMsg()
Select
    Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        ExitLoop
    Case $msg = $AutoClose
        $NumTickets = GUICtrlRead($NumTicketsBox)
        $iState = 1
        $i = 0
    Case Else
        If $iState = 1 Then
            If $i >= $NumTickets Then
                $iState = 3
                ContinueLoop
            EndIf
            ControlClick("[CLASS:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX]", "", "", "left", 1, 143, 474)
            $iState = 2
            $iTimer = TimerInit()
        ElseIf $iState = 2 Then
            If TimerDiff($iTimer) < 2000 Then ContinueLoop
            ControlClick("[CLASS:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX]", "", "", "left", 1, 700, 337)
            $iTimer = TimerInit()
            $i = $i + 1
            $iState = 1
        ElseIf $iState = 3 Then
            If TimerDiff($iTimer) < 1000 Then ContinueLoop
            If $i <= 0 Then
                $iState = 1
                ContinueLoop
            EndIf
            ControlClick("[CLASS:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX]", "", "", "left", 1, 59, 337)
            $iTimer = TimerInit()
            $i = $i - 1
        EndIf
EndSelect
WEnd
```

**And this is the output of the >>>> Control <<<< section of the Window Info:**

```
>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX
Instance:   1
ClassnameNN:    MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX1
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 172092576
Text:   
Position:   8, 194
Size:   760, 620
ControlClick Coords:    59, 339
Style:  0x56000000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x0002117A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

----EDIT----

The closest thing I can come up with to a similar solution is located here: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/94736-noob-controlclick/ but this doesn't appear to be working for me. Once again, any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
ControlClick("[CLASS:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX]", "", 172092576, "left", 1, 700, 337)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry this went so long without any attention, I stopped paying attention to it. I'll try it tomorrow when I can get to my dev machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ; 2=subStr
$sTitle = "Mozilla"
ControlClick($sTitle, "", "[CLASSNN:MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX1]", "primary", 1, 700, 337)
```